# Do I need to include partition key WHERE clauses on both tables of a join?

Tags: sql

I'm writing an SQL query that joins two tables, each of which have a partition key (`pk` below).  Do I need to include an appropriate WHERE statement on both tables?  For example:

```
SELECT t1.x, t2.y
FROM t1, t2
WHERE t1.pk = 100 AND t2.pk = 100 and t1.id = t2.id
```

Or is it sufficient to provide the `pk = 100` WHERE clause for just one of the tables?

**EDIT** I should clarify: I'm wondering what is best practice for performance, not just getting the right rows.  Also these tables have both `id` and `pk` as primary keys.

Comment: `WHERE t1.pk = 100  and t1.id = t2.id` is sufficient

Comment: Is id a unique primary key  and PartionKey pk  a non unique key.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the JOIN for better performance,

```
SELECT t1.x,
       t2.y
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.pk = 100
```

Answer (score 0):

When you join two tables as shown below (A modified version of your code) as a first step it would return an intermediate result set that satisfies the condition t1.id = t2.id.

The where condition will be applied to this whole result set. Hence it's enough to filter by any values (i.e t1.pk = 100 or t2.pk = 100)

```
SELECT t1.x, t2.y FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id WHERE t1.pk = 100
```

Comment: Is there a performance benefit from specifying it twice?  See edit above.

Comment: I would say it will degrade the performance as you are searching the data collection twice to do the same operation.